# Converting a number into time (0,5 of an hour = 00:30:00)

Tags: r, time

I am trying to convert a number into time format.
For example: 
 I calculate how long has to be charged an electric car at the charging station of 11 kWh.

- Energy demand - 2,8 kWh
- Charging time = 2,8 kWh/11 kWh = 0,257 h
- 0,257 h = 15 min 25 sec. = 00:15:25

How can I convert `0,257 h` into `00:15:25` in R?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: That is what I have done:

a<-summarise(group_by(x, Time interval), `energy demand`= median*25/100,
             charging time = `energy demand`/11)

25 - energy consumption - 25kWh/100km
median = 11.306km (distance)
Here I have received a table with the following values:
Time interval - 00:00 - 00:30
energy demand - 2.827 kWh
charging time - 0,257 h
I know that there are some functions which can convert numbers into time series, for example POSIXlt and package "chron". But I can´t comprehend conditions which must be established
Could You help me to write the code?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the example, we will assume that the input is less than 24 (but if that is not the case these could be modified to handle that depending on the definition of what such an input should produce).

**1) chron::times** Use chron `times` like this.  `times` measures times in fractions of a day so divide the hours (.257) by 24 to give the fraction of a day that it represents.

```
library(chron)

times(.257 / 24)
## [1] 00:15:25
```

This gives a chron `"times"` class object.  If `x` is such an object use `format(x)` to convert it to a character string, if desired.

**2) POSIXct** This uses no packages although it is longer.  It returns the time as a character string.  POSIXct measures time in seconds and so multiply the hours (.257) by 3600 as there are 3600 seconds in an hour.

```
format(as.POSIXct("1970-01-01") + 3600 * .257, "%H:%M:%S")
## [1] "00:15:25"
```

**2a)** This variation would also work. It is longer but it involves no conversion factors.  It returns a character string.

```
format(as.POSIXct("1970-01-01") + as.difftime(.257, units = "hours"), "%H:%M:%S")
## [1] "00:15:25"
```

**Updates:** Added (2).  Also added (2a) and improved (2).

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @GGrothendieck seems to be the way to go here.  But if you had to do this in base R, you could just compute the hour, minute, and second components and build the time string manually:

```
x <- 2.257                               # number of hours
total <- round(x*60*60, digits=0)        # the total number of seconds
hours <- trunc(total / (60*60))
minutes <- trunc((x - hours) * 60)
seconds <- total %% 60

ts <- paste0(formatC(hours, width=2, flag="0"), ":",
             formatC(minutes, width=2, flag="0"), ":",
             formatC(seconds, width=2, flag="0"))
ts

[1] "02:15:25"
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank You very much!
I'll try Your way too.

Answer (score 3):

The [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org) solution would use the `hms` package:

```r
hms::hms(0.257 * 60^2)  
#> 00:15:25.2
```

Gives you an object of classes `hms` and `difftime`. If you want a string:

```r
format(hms::hms(0.257 * 60^2))
#> [1] "00:15:25.2"
```